# how to prevent sync of nested array object between controller and component in ember

Tags: ember.js

I am working on *Ember.js 2.12.0*

How to prevent sync of nested array object between controller and component.

For ember string its working but for nested array object its not working.

below is ember twiddle link

[ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/dd6924523f58a180066fcb129a6eadfb?route=%2Fabout)

*In twiddle if you change the value of **String** and **arr** and click to HOME route and again come to ABOUT route then you can see that value of **String** gets changed but the value of **arr** is not gets changed*

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is a [primitive typed](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values) object, but Array is not. So when the component modifies the `str`, it doesn't reflect to the controller's `str`. Because you are copying its values in component. You can try this by adding `{{str}}` to the `about.hbs`. See it doesn't changed. (In your current twiddle.)

But the array is different. It's not just a value. Component's arr is the same with the controllers arr. When the component modifies it, you can see the change it in `about.hbs`. (Also refer to the *pass by value, pass by reference*.)

On the other hand, controllers are singleton, they stores the last values on them. So whenever you changed the array, you can see it is persistent.

Above, I mentioned about causes. Below I'll mention about solutions:

1. Alternative 1, clone the array before sending it to the component.
2. Alternative 2, reset the array in route's specific hooks.
3. Alternative 3, use `model` hook to generate and send the array.

I've also modified your component, see in [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3d2b91475a9b0fd4a0bd60348dcca387).

Further, never define an array in an object definition. Because all the instances of that class will share the same array instance. (It is also written in somewhere at [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/).)

Comment: #ykaragol thanks for response. can u please check twiddle now.If we reset the ARR value in setupcontroller using some variable then its not working.

Comment: @dilipkumar which twiddle? [this one](https://ember-twiddle.com/3d2b91475a9b0fd4a0bd60348dcca387) is working

Comment: can you please check [this one](https://ember-twiddle.com/ea710917665fbb69721042af93c22063)

Comment: you are again passing the same reference to the component.

Comment: you need something like this: `let arr = [];
    Ember.$.extend(true, arr, this.get('arrm'));
    controller.set('arr', arr); `

Answer (score 0):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController(controller, model){
    controller.set("arr",[{name:'ravi kumar'}])
  }
});
```

this will make sure you always get arr reset.

this file you create in routes/about.js